# python - Is it possible to combine 2 functions together to create 1 function?

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine these functions together to create 1 function?

```
def checkinput():
    while True:
        try:
            name=input("whats your name?")
            return name
        except ValueError:
            print("error!")
```

Combined with:

```
def checkage():
       while True:
           try:
               age=input("whats your age?")
               return age
           except ValueError:
               print("error!")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by combine?

Comment: Just define it in one function (eg: have one function call other the two functions)

Comment: better specify the problem you have rather than the solution you want

Comment: @EdwardCollins `def newfunction: return checkinput() checkage()`

Comment: @EdwardCollins - don't tell us what you want the code to look like, tell us that you want to ask someone for their name and age, and you've got this code so far...

Comment: You might want to go to the [python chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)... your problems seem to be on a bit more fundamental level.

Answer (score 4):

You can refactor the code to create one function that handles both cases, by recognizing the parts that are the same, and parameterizing the other parts.

```
def check_value(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            val=input(prompt)
            return val
        except ValueError:
            print("error!")
```

The only difference between the two functions (other than trivial differences like variable names) was the prompt shown by the `input` function. We make that a parameter to the new unified function, and call it like this:

```
x = check_input("What's your name?")
y = check_input("What's your age?")
```

Why you expect `input` to possibly raise a `ValueError` is a different question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generalize your code, you could write *one* function that can ask any number of questions.

You can create a function that looks like this:

```
def ask_a_question(prompt):
   while True:
       try:
           answer = input(prompt)
       except ValueError:
           print("Error!")
       else:
           return answer
```

For example, in your `main()` function, you could have a list of prompts:

```
prompts = {
    'name': 'What is your name?',
    'age': 'How old are you?',
    'dog': 'Do you love dogs more than cats? (yes, you do)',
}
```

And finally you would create a loop that would ask all your questions one by one:

```
answers = {}  # a dictionary of answers

for key, prompt in prompts.items():
    answers[key] = ask_a_question(prompt)
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas on how to reduce duplication of similar functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily call a function from other functions:

```
def check_user_data():
    checkinput()
    checkage()
```

But really, this is a silly thing to do. If you just want their name and age you'd be better off doing something like this:

```
 def get_user_info():
     name = input("What is your name? ")
     age = input("What is your age? ")
     return name, age
```

You're never going to get a `ValueError` when you're just taking input - if you were doing `int(input('What is your age? '))` you could get a `ValueError`, but otherwise the rest of your code is superfluous.

Comment: thats duplication, better make a "generic" function that takes arguement to pass in the `input` function?

Comment: @FooBarUser I often do this. Why is it considered duplication? It also seems easier to read.

Comment: @Keikoku i think chepner's answer is the best way, if you had 10 input parameters you would write 10 functions.

Comment: @FooBarUser Oops sorry, I thought you were referring to defining a function just to call other functions. Yes I would agree with the 10 input example.

Comment: I don't even know that I'd go that far - I've provided an example that I think is a bit more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
def check_input_and_age():
    return checkinput(), checkage()
```