# check if number and convert Fahrenheit

Tags: python-3.x, validation, converters

could someone tell me what is the main rule to connect two functions together? I have two functions: one that checks if input is number and another that converts Celsius to Fahrenheit. How do I combine them? I am at the level that at the moment I would like just to understand how to combine them, but any advice on how to make it more pythonic is appreciated as well.
Thank you for advices!

First:

```
def is_number():
    user_input = input ('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
    if (user_input.isdigit()):
        return user_input
    else:
        print ('It is not a number!')
        return is_number()
is_number()
```

and second:

```
t = input('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
def Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(t):
    fahrenheit = (t * 1.8) + 32
    print('>>> ' + str(t) + 'C' + ' converted to Fahrenheit is: ' +     str(fahrenheit) + 'F')
Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(float(t))
```

(possible duplicate is not a duplicate as even the question is not very clear there and it does not answer my question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Is it possible to combine 2 functions together to create 1 function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434097/python-is-it-possible-to-combine-2-functions-together-to-create-1-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible way would be to call `is_number()` from within `Celsius_to_Fahrenheit()`:

```py
def Celsius_to_Fahrenheit():
  t = float(is_number())
  fahrenheit = (t * 1.8) + 32
  print('>>> ' + str(t) + 'C' + ' converted to Fahrenheit is: ' + str(fahrenheit) + 'F')

Celsius_to_Fahrenheit()
```

The `is_number()` function can stay as-is. There is no need to call this function separately now.

Comment: thank you for advice, I just now noticed the mistake in my code as it does not work with negative numbers... maybe you know an easier way to fix it that to use Try Except block? appreciate

Comment: @new_neri You can use a try-catch block for that. For example, you can change `is_number()` function's code to: `try:
        user_input = input('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a numeric value")
        return is_number()
    else:
        return user_input`

Comment: @new_neri Please don't forget to select the green check-mark for the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @A Busy Programmer this one does not work for letters, but works for negative numbers, I get this error : "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'" . I tried many variations, but I just cannot make it work for numbers, negative numbers and letters for some reasons... thank you for help!

Comment: @new_neri This should handle all sorts of inputs in the `is_number()` function: `user_input = input('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        return user_input
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a numeric value")
        return is_number()`

Answer (score 0):

The two functions can run independent of each other, so easiest would be to simply combine code into one function:

```
def Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(t):
    while not t.isdigit():
        print ('It is not a number!')
        t = input ('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
    t = float(t)
    fahrenheit = (t * 1.8) + 32
    print('>>> ' + str(t) + 'C' + ' converted to Fahrenheit is: ' + str(fahrenheit) + 'F')    

t = input ('>>> Please enter a temperature in Celsius: ')
Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call one function from within another:

```
def convert_celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius_temperature):
    if celsius_temperature.isdigit():
        fahrenheit_temperature = celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius_temperature)
        return fahrenheit_temperature

def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius_temperature):
    fahrenheit_temperature = (t * 1.8) + 32
    return fahrenheit_temperature
```